# Where can I find a list of synonyms and hyponyms for different food types?

Tags: synonyms, hypernyms, food

I'm trying to find a list of synonyms between various food types for a programming project I am working on with searching English language phrases. I was originally going to ask this on Stack Overflow, but this question wasn't necessarily related to programming.

In the list I'm looking for, I'd like to be able to know the synonyms and hyponyms for food types. For example:

- Synonym: sandwich — sub
- Hyponyms: Mexican — taco, burrito; fruit — orange, apple, banana

Are there any lists that exist that might help bootstrap my efforts?

Comment: Have a go with the [OneLook reverse dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "one-way synonym". The term you are looking for is [*hyponym*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy). I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Princeton Wordnet will be your best resource - http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=sandwich&i=1&h=10000000#c

Answer (score 1):

Good luck with this one.

When you look up a word on the website Wordnik, the bottom of the page lists various synonyms for the word.  I just did this for [sandwich](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sandwich), with interesting results.

First, they (correctly) don't list *submarine* as a synonym for *sandwich*, but as a *hyponym*. In a similar vain, *orange* and *apple* aren't listed as synonyms or hyponyms for [fruit](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fruit), but as words that are found in a *reverse dictionary lookup*.

Although it would take a lot of work, this Wordnik feature could prove helpful for your efforts.  As to how you could restrict your culling to words related to food, you could always start with the Wordnik entry for [*food*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/food) – that might make a good "root node".  Both *fruit* and *sandwich* are listed there, under *Words that are found in the same context*; so is *taco*.  And check out what delectable words you find when you look up [*mexican*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/mexican), and see what words are *tagged*!

Comment: However, there is almost no semantic area with more regional and sociolinguistic lexical variation than that of food, particularly popular food, most especially snacks and local specialties. When one travels to a place where a foreign language is spoken, dictionaries are famously useless for decoding menus, since everything goes by a local name. As J.R. say, good luck.